# how to get user ID (uid) by third_party_id in Facebook API 2.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook API 1.0-2.0 has FQL, so I can get ID by FQL.
But FQL will be removed in version 2.1.

```
  $result = self::getAPI()->api("fql", "GET", array('q' => 'select uid from user where third_party_id="'.$thirdPartyId.'"', 'access_token' => Const::APPACCESS_TOKEN));
```

so question is how to get user id by third_party_id in API 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

You could still get facebook uid by facebook third party id by sending GET request to this Graph API endpoint:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[THIRD_PARTY_ID]?access_token=[APP_ACCESS_TOKEN]`

The response will have two fields: `name` and `id`, and the `id` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: This is no longer possible with Graph API v2.1. There's no endpoint in the Graph API where you can pass the `third_party_Id`. You should think about using the app-scoped user_id.

Comment: Thanks!
(it is bad because we have third-part-service which use third-part-id)

Comment: You should be able to use FQl until August 7t, 2016, so maybe just wait a while and see if FB will also create a `third_party_id` endpoint for the Graph API.